# Custom ListView Items repeated

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to add dynamic textview to listview items.textviews can be of 1-2 or more than that depending on data I have succeed in adding the textview but problem is textviews are repeated on scroll.

I am creating new object of textview each time in loop.I am aware of the problem that android tries to reuse existing view but i have to add new view every time.

Here is my code in custom adapter:

```
public class ViewHolder {
    TextView text1;
    LinearLayout linearLayout;
    TextView t;
    TextView t1;
}
```

getView method

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.two_item_icon_text, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.text1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {

        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    }

    holder.linearLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lin_lay_dynamic);
    holder.text1.setText("" + DATA1[position]);
    String tmp, dateparsed;
    dateparsed = DATA1[position].substring(0, DATA1[position].indexOf(":"));
    for (int x = 0; x < calendareventholder1.size(); x++) {

        objHolder = (CalendarEventHolder) calendareventholder1.get(x);

        if (objHolder.opendate.equals(displaydate[current])) {

            tmp = objHolder.dtstarttime.toString().substring(0, objHolder.dtstarttime.toString().indexOf(":"));

            if (Integer.parseInt(tmp) >= Integer.parseInt(dateparsed) && Integer.parseInt(tmp) < Integer.parseInt(dateparsed) + 1) {
                holder.t = new TextView(convertView.getContext());
                holder.t.setText(":-d ");
                holder.t.setOnClickListener(this);

                if (Common.isChildSessionAlerted(String.valueOf(objHolder.id), getApplicationContext(), object1)) {

                    holder.t.setText(holder.t.getText() + objHolder.dtstarttime + " " + objHolder.dtendtime + " :-a");
                } else {
                    holder.t.setText(holder.t.getText() + objHolder.dtstarttime + " " + objHolder.dtendtime);
                }
                holder.t.setTag(objHolder.id);
                holder.t.setTextSize(Common.getPreferenceInt(getApplicationContext(), Common.PREF_FONT_SIZE, 10));
                holder.t.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                holder.t.setText(getSmiledText(ScheduleActivity.this,
                holder.t.getText().toString()));
                holder.linearLayout.addView(holder.t);
                holder.t1 = new TextView(convertView.getContext());
                holder.t1.setOnClickListener(this);
                holder.t1.setText(objHolder.title);
                holder.t1.setTag(objHolder.id);

                holder.t1.setTextSize(Common.getPreferenceInt(getApplicationContext(), Common.PREF_FONT_SIZE, 10));
                holder.t1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                holder.linearLayout.addView(holder.t1);
            }
        }
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a little hard to really understand what is in holder since it isn't super descriptive, but if I am reading your question right, the reason you are getting repeated items is because you are just adding `Views` and never deleting what was there before. `ListView` recycles views, meaning what was there previously stays there. As it scrolls it actually keeps reusing views rather than creating new ones. I won't go into detail because there are a bunch of question on here with similar problems. But at the top you should do

```
getView() {
    /*previous stuff, and holder.linearLayout must have been set!*/
    if(holder.linearLayout.getChildCount() > 0)
        holder.linearLayout.removeAllViews();
```

This way any views already there will be removed. One last thing, you should also check out [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70). Immensely helpful in understanding why you have to do what I posted.

Comment: No problem. One quick thing, you should probably do a check to know whether to call `removeAllViews` or not. No point in calling it when there are no children in the `LinearLayout`. I'll update that.

Comment: Thanks in millions andy, You saved my day.